# Правильное разбиение на классы

Tags: ооп, php, шаблоны-проектирования

Товарищи, помогите разрешить противоречие) вопрос скорее абстрактный, чем касательно реализации
Есть некий опрос. Опрос, понятно дело, проходит не один человек, и так или иначе возникнет необходимость в выводе информации по этому опросу по всем ответившим. При заполнении опроса пользователем создается отдельный объект опроса под одного пользователя. Класс будет иметь все необходимые методы для получения информации по нему из базы(опять же, по одному прошедшему опрос). Вопрос в следующем: когда нужно будет выводить статистику, что правильней - вызывать на каждого пользователя по объекту опроса, записывать все в какой-либо буфер, а потом уже отдельно (при необходимости) обсчитывать весь полученный массив информации для подведения статистики? Или же все-таки нужно создавать отдельный класс под все опросы, и если да, то как должен быть связан класс "опросы" с классом "опрос"? Скорее всего прозвучало глупо, но мне не хватает терминологии чтобы сформулировать получше, за это извиняюсь)
P.S.: если отошлете какие-то ссылки на литературу по этому поводу - только спасибо скажу)

Answer (score 1):

У меня сомнения в правильности подхода. Неужели действительно есть необходимость пользоваться собственными программными средствами для сбора окончательной статистики с выгрузкой всей информации в память, не возложив данный труд на базу данных? А если у тебя будут тысячи пользователей, памяти и времени хватит для работы скрипта?

Мне кажется примерно такая схема должна быть, т.к. каждая отдельно выделяемая сущность должна иметь свой класс:

1. класс пользователь, который
       содержит всю информацию о текущем
       авторизованном пользователе и методы
       работы с ним.
2. класс опрос, который использует
       класс пользователя и осуществляет
       его работу с опросом.
3. класс статистики, который для
       сбора и обсчитывания информации
       должен пользоваться средствами базы
       данных и его запросами, по
       возможности не прибегая к
       использованию других классов.

Что касается самого вопроса, то можно реализовать отдельный класс той же статистики, который будет высчитывать информацию по необходимости. То есть запрашивать данные одного пользователя классом пользователь, суммировать нужные сведения в буфере и высвобождать его перед запросом другого пользователя. В конце нужные сведения будут в буфере и готовы к выводу. Правда при таком подходе может проседать производительность.

Answer (score 1):

Как я бы проектировал подобную систему.

Создал следующие классы

`модель_опроса`. Этот класс содержит данные  опроса и базовые функции.

`загрузчик_опроса`. Этот класс получает ссылку на модель_опроса и "условный номер" (имя файла, id в базе, кусок json/xml) и умеет сохранить/открыть опрос.

`список_опросов`. хранит массив опросов. Умеет сохранить/загрузить опросы, получив ссылку "загрузчик_опроса".

уже при такой модели, можно делать многое. К примеру, нужно вывести в виде html список. Для этого пишется "загрузчик_опроса" который умеет печатать один опрос.

Теперь ответ на вопрос - как считать статистику. Для этого в список вопросов нужно добавить метод "посчитать" (некоторые здесь скажут, что лучше сделать отдельный класс для этого, но это нужно ещё подумать). Метод посчитать получает один параметр - функцию. Внутри он делает простое - в цикле для каждого элемента ее вызывает, а результат складывает. И собственно результат сложения возвращает. В таком случае очень легко делать статистику под что угодно - только функцию новую написать. А так как в php есть [анонимные фукнции](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php), то простенькие функции можно писать налету. Эта функция должна получать параметром "модель_опроса".

Учитывая [статью](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/functions.variable-functions.php), можно будет писать код вида

```
function positive($one_pull) {
   return $one_pull->yes > $one_pull->no;
}
$statistic = $pull_list.calc('positive');
```

или даже

```
$positive = function($one_pull) {
   return $one_pull->yes > $one_pull->no;
}
$statistic = $pull_list.calc($positive);

// method call
function call($cc) {
  $c = 0;
  foreach ($one : $list) {
    $c += $cc($one);
  }
  return $c;
}
```

Похожим образом можно определить функцию filter, которая будет получать предикат (функцию, которая получает один опрос и возвращает true|false) и возвращает новый список. Этот же предикат можно использовать для подсчета опросов, удовлетворяющих определенному условию - нужно функцию фильтр немного переписать.

Зачем все так сложно? очень просто. Те, кто будет писать функцию для фильтрации запроса абсолютно не интересно знать, как запрос сохраняется в json. Поэтому, ему будет легко протестировать на отдельных запросах. Если кто то решит написать сохранение в оракловую базу, ему не обязательно знать, как оно на печать выводиться. И он не будет бояться, что добавив одно поле в "модель_опроса", он сломает статистику.

(я давно на php не писал, могу делать банальные глупости, но я старался передать идею).